# how can I justify the entire body of the document

Tags: justification, apa7

this my code. I want the body text to be justify

```
\documentclass[table,a4paper,man,floatsintext]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
%........
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

begin{document}
Aux cours de mes activités extrascolaires, à ce jour je souhaite faire des études en Master en administration de pétrole et de gaz. Ce domaine n'est en rapport indirect qu'avec certains des activités et je souhaite agrandir mes capacités intellectuelles sur celui-ci et acquérir des compétences en ce domaine. Sur-ce, votre université UNICAF me semble le mieux adapter en corrélation avec mes travaux.  J'ai rencontré plusieurs articles de vos étudiants qui exposent tous des bonnes remarques et perspectives concernant votre université multinationale. Son système d'éducation en ligne permet une flexibilité, aussi à tout genre pour les étudiants à d'autre bout du monde.
\end{document}
```

only the left side comes out justify, i can't figure out how to put the whole text body into justification

Comment: by default latex justifies but if you use a journal class then you should use whatever format they specify, better to use a generic class like article if you do not want to follow the house style

Comment: mine doesn't justify with the apa style

Comment: exactly. that is what I mean. If the publisher doesn't want manuscript submissions justified that is their choice. That is the whole reason for having publisher classes like apa 7, to remove style choices from the author.